# RestController Setting default Header for GetMapping

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, http-headers

Good Morning,

I have a RestController controller where I have a GetMapping using a header.
If that header does not come with any value, I want to route to a default method, ¿is there any way?
¿Is there any way to set the value of a default header when the rest Client dont send it?

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/demo")

@Log4j2
public class RestDemoController{

@GetMapping( value = "/version", headers = "x-api-version=v.1.0")
public String getHeaderValue(@RequestHeader(value=ApiVersionConstans.API_VERSION_HEADER_CODE) String version) {
    log.debug("Returning version header");
    return ApiVersionConstans.API_VERSION_HEADER_CODE;
}

@GetMapping(value = "/version", headers = "x-api-version=v.1.0_default")

public String getAnoherHeader(@RequestHeader(value=ApiVersionConstans.API_VERSION_HEADER_CODE) String version) {
    log.debug("Looking for exisiting tokens");
    return "This is another header";
}
```

}

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

```
@GetMapping("/version")
public String getDefaultHeader(@RequestHeader(value=ApiVersionConstans.API_VERSION_HEADER_CODE, defaultValue="your default value") String version) {
    // ...
    return "This is default header";
}
```

When you set `@RequestHeader#defaultValue`, the header is not required and its value is set to `version` when the header is missing. 
I think javadoc of `@RequestHeader` is helpful for you:
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestHeader.html#required--